# I want to check a IF formula by using the IFS function

Tags: excel, if-statement, ifs

I have the following IF function, which tells us the source of some data in Excel.

```
=IF(D168=T168, " ", IF(AND(S168=0, R168<>0), "Invalid number", IF(AND(R168=0, Q168<>0),"Invalid Text", IF(AND(D168=0, T168<>0), "Source X", IF(AND(T168<>0, T168<>F168, OR (T168=G168, T168=O168, T168=P168)), "Source Y", " ")))))
```

Now I want to check that this formula is pulling the right source with an IFS function. I have tried IFS(D168=T168, " ", S168=0 R168<>0, "Invalid Number") but this formula returns an error.

I want to basically translate the IF formula above into an IFS formula.

Comment: How did your translation of `AND(S168=0, R168<>0)` become `S168=0 R168<>0`?

Comment: I'm not sure how to carry over the IF(And) part to the IFS formula

Comment: Just carry it the same way it is in the `IF`, i.e. `AND(S168=0, R168<>0)`

Comment: like this? =IFS(D168=T168, " ", AND(S168=0 R168<>0, "Invalid number"))    I still get an error.

Comment: You did not carry the `AND` exactly as it is again. `IFS(D168=T168, " ", AND(S168=0, R168<>0), "Invalid Number")` is it really that hard?

Comment: apologies, i have solved the problem now. Thanks for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax for the IFS function in Microsoft Excel is:

```
=IFS( condition1, return1 [,condition2, return2] ... [,condition127, return127] )
```

So after S=168, what value?

And don't forget the commas!

You probably omitted the AND. Because that is your 'condition 2'. i.e. something that will return a boolean true or false result.

```
AND(S168=0, R168<>0)
```

Leading to:

```
=IFS(D168=T168, " ", AND(S168=0, R168<>0), "Invalid Number")
```

etc, etc.

Let me know if that works for you.